# FeignClient with absolute URL doesn't work using Spring Cloud Loadbalancer in Hoxton.RELEASE

Tags: spring-cloud

I have a feign client with absolute host url (target host not registered in eureka)

```
@FeignClient(name = "feedback-client", url = "http://some.absolute.url") 
interface FeedbackClient {

   @RequestMapping(value = ["/feedback"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
   fun findAll(@RequestParam("page") page: Int): Page<Feedback>
}
```

Everything works fine with Spring Boot 2.2.1, until i disable Ribbon using the below configuration in `application.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    loadbalancer:
      ribbon:
        enabled: false
```

Feign client starts giving below error:

```
s.c.o.l.FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient : Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service <absolute http url>
```

I a trying to use `spring cloud loadbalancer` instead of ribbon, which is causing this issue.

I have added the below dependency in `build.gradle`

```
 compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer')
```

Any help? Does Feign support `spring cloud loadbalancer` with static list of servers?

Github Repo to reproduce the scenario:

https://github.com/cancerian0684/demo-openfeign

**Dependencies**:

- Spring Boot 2.2.1
- Spring Cloud Hoxton.RELEASE

### Update 21st Dec 2019

This bug (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/259) has been fixed in Spring Boot `2.2.2.RELEASE` and Spring Cloud `Hoxton.SR1`

Loadbalancer shall work fine with this release.

Comment: Probably some problems with Hoxton release. Your example works with Boot 2.1.9, Greenwich and Loadbalancer 2.1.4

Comment: This bug was fixed in Spring Cloud `Hoxton.SR1` based on Spring boot `2.2.2.RELEASE`. Related bug information - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/259

Comment: Ok, nice to hear it